# Get table cells with their indexes in a docx using OpenXml SDK: Does OpenXmlElement.Elements() return the elements in the correct order?

Tags: ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk

I want to get the cells in a table and know their indexes using the OpenXML SDK.

[OpenXmlElement.Elements()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.openxmlelement.elements?view=openxml-2.8.1) enumerates the child nodes of an element. Are the results guaranteed to be in the same order as they appear in the document? If they are, then this could be used in a simple solution.

If not, then what would be a simple way to determine this? I could order them by the counts of ElementsBefore() for each element, but it seems like there should be a more direct way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source code for the OpenXML SDK, I see that it starts with the first child, and moves onto the next ("Gets the OpenXmlElement element with the specified type that follows the current OpenXmlElement element.") so I am happy that the enumeration is in the correct order.